# Add Internal Email Distro to All Marketing Cloud sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, list, content-builder, send-email

We have 40 distributed teams that send emails and they use multiple lists and DE's.  How can my team be copied on every email we send through SFMC?  Other email platforms allow for you to CC an internal distro on email sends.

Comment: You can do a cc/bcc but whoever is sending the emails would need to remember to do it each time they send something out. Plus, this would cost you extra supermessages and could mess with the tracking data. Take a look at this article: http://www.hernalsteen.tech/2021/03/automatically-ccing-and-or-bccing-static-and-dynamic-addresses-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud/

Comment: You can also look at using a seedlist https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_partner_seed_lists.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

I would create an internal data extension and then BCC that data extension either in Journey Builder or when you utilize single sending.